# Add manual legend for edges in visNetwork

Tags: r, legend

I'm trying to create a legend for my network map through visNetwork.

I understand that legends in visNetwork are generally for nodes, so I would have to create one manually for the edges.

This question here is basically the same:
[Adding a legend in visNetwork for edge color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602251/adding-a-legend-in-visnetwork-for-edge-color/38629687#38629687)

But I don't understand the answer, I've also tried reading up on it and so far my results look like this: 
[image: Weird looking legend]

```
ledges <- data.frame(color = c("teal", "grey", "deeppink"),
                     font.align = "top")

visNetwork(nodes, links) %>% visGroups(groupname = "WLZ", size=45) %>% visEvents(stabilizationIterationsDone="function () {this.setOptions( { physics: false } );}") %>%       visGroups(groupname = "Data", color = "teal") %>%
  visGroups(groupname = "Location in Common", color = "grey") %>% visGroups(groupname = "Money", color = "deeppink") %>% 
  visLegend(addEdges = ledges)
```

Have I just written it wrong?

Basically I want a legend that says Relationships: Data = Teal, Location in Common = Grey and Money = Deep Pink

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is labeled the relanships. What the names of it? Is "Data", "Location in Common" and "Money" if were, then,
according to [the answer of: Adding a legend in visNetwork for edge color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602251/adding-a-legend-in-visnetwork-for-edge-color) try to replace your ledges for this:

```
ledges <- data.frame(color = c("teal", "grey", "deeppink")
                 label = c("Data","Location in Common", "Money") # relationship's names
)
```

After that replace your last code for this:

```
visNetwork(nodes, links) %>% 
  visGroups(groupname = "WLZ", size=45) %>% 
  visEvents(stabilizationIterationsDone="function () {this.setOptions( { physics: false } );}") %>% 
  visLegend(addEdges = ledges)
```